How do I keep my points on the correct position on the background image, even when I resize the viewport?
I have a background image which covers the screen and is centered vertical and horizontal. The points on this image need to stay put on that specific position. How do i accomplish this, even when i resize my window?
I like to make it work the same way as this page: https://shorturl.at/1pFd8
I assume I need some javascript to calculate for the resizing but i'm not sure how to proceed.
Thank you.
test page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Blend between Day & Night">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="">
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:ital,wght@0,300..900;1,300..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image0.webp" alt="Image" class="responsive-image" />
            <div class="point" style="top: 20%; left: 40%;"></div>
            <div class="point" style="top: 60%; left: 70%;"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Figtree';
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(47, 148, 33);
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .responsive-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .point {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border:  1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(47, 148, 33);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99;
  }

I've tried Gemini that provide me this code but the calculation of the points were very large and to much out of range.
const image = document.querySelector('.responsive-image');
const points = document.querySelectorAll('.point');

function positionPoints() {
  const imageRect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
  const imageWidth = imageRect.width;
  const imageHeight = imageRect.height;

  points.forEach(point => {
    const topPercentage = parseFloat(point.style.top);
    const leftPercentage = parseFloat(point.style.left);

    const topPx = imageHeight * topPercentage / 100;
    const leftPx = imageWidth * leftPercentage / 100;

    point.style.top = `${topPx}px`;
    point.style.left = `${leftPx}px`;
  });
}

// Initial positioning and on resize
positionPoints();
window.addEventListener('resize', positionPoints);

